# How to convert a project into a library project - and then use it

Tags: android

I have had a fully working app on google play for many months now.

I have been making lots of different versions by editing/un-editing it, but understand that the proper way to do this is convert your app into a library project and then have a variety of different projects / manifest files which then include the library.

I know I can go to properties/android and click "is library" to make my existing project into a library, but then what would my new "wrapper" project look like? Is there a nice online article describing this process?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, my question isn't "how do I make a library project" (I think I've got that sorted), my question is "what does a project that does nothing other than execute the library look like?"... would it contain any .java files at all?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html. check the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a combination of guesswork and experimentation, I ended up with the following recipe...

Step one, clear the guts form the original projects manifest, so that it ends up simply as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.mylibraryname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.00" >

</manifest>
```

Then in properties-android, tick "Is Library", then build the new library project.

Step 2, Ask eclipse to make a new android application project, but uncheck create activity.

Step 3. In the new project go to properties - android and in the Library box, select add, and you should now be able to select the original project as a library.

Step 4. Now paste the guts of the manifest that you took from the original project and paste them into the body of the new manifest.

Now just click run - nothing else to add.

**Things to watch out for.** If the original project had assets (like fonts), then copy these to the new project as they don't seem to get accessed from a library.

Your library's references to resource ID's are no longer simply constants, so they are not allowed in switch-case statements (convert to if-then-else).

If you have references in the manifest like: `android:name=".my_class"`, then these will need to be changed to their full names like so `android:name="com.company.mylibraryname.my_class"`.

Answer (score 0):

This artical shows basics of how to create  library project with a good tutorial [AndroidLibraryProjects](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)

and We have the Android docs , which mention what constrains you should keep in mind while creating Library project here is the link [Android Library Project doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)